# Set an .Rmd in a package to write files to the current project working directory

Tags: r, package, knitr, environment

I have a `.Rmd` which I use to report on data quality in a number of different r projects. It would then split the data to remove subsets with missing data, and interpolate missing results where appropriate. It would do this via a write.csv command to a file path in the form of "./Cleansed_data/"

**To make an example**

1. open rstudio
2. go to the rhs 'project' menu , and select and make a new
   project wherever you'd like
3. go to the lhs 'new script' drop down and
   select 'new .Rmd'
4. change the output to .pdf and hit ok
5. in the last r
   chunk include `write.csv(mtcars, file = "mtcars.csv")`
6. hit the 'knit
   pdf' button, save the report as `"writeFile.Rmd"` to your project working directory, and
   let it run.

Previously I moved this .Rmd from place to place, however now I would like to built it into an internal package. I have included it (as the documentation indicates to) into `inst/rmd` within the package directory.

1. In order to do this build or open any package you have access to
2. add the file to `inst/rmd` (create it if this doesn't exist)
3. rebuild the package

I then rebuild the package and open a new project. I load my new package and attempt to run the document via the `render` command using the `system.file` command to locate the `.rmd` like so

```
rmarkdown::render(input = system.file("rmd/writeFile.Rmd", package="MyPackage"), 
              output_file = "writeFile.pdf", output_dir = "./Cars/)
```

This will render the report from the package build into the folder from `output_dir`, however, there are a number of pitfalls here. First, if I omit the `output_dir` argument, the report will render into the package library, usually located in the libraries  r installation in the c drive. This is however fixable.

What I can't get around is that when the `.Rmd` hits the `write.csv()` then (I believe) the .Rmd is being rendered in the package environment at the time, the working directory of which is the package library folder, not the current project directory.

**The Questions**

1. How can I inform the template in the package what the current working directory is for the rstudio project? I'm vaguely aware there might be a rstudio api package? I have nearly no understanding of what it is though, or if this would provide a solution.
2. If this is either outright impossible or just potentially a *very bad idea* how can I modify the workflow to successfully retrieve a number of r object outputs into the environment or the working directory, on the call to the report, without having to modify the report for each different project? Further, why specifically is this approach such a bad plan?

Comment: So I have a functional solution. In the `.rmd`: `write.csv(mtcars, file =
              paste0(rstudioapi::getActiveProject(),
                     "mtcars.csv"))`. I'll leave the question up though for a time longer to gether more apporaches/warnings.

Comment: Not sure if I got all the details, therefore this is a comment instead of an answer: You could save the working directory `wd<-getwd()` before you call `render`. `wd` will be available in the RMD file. There you can use `knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = wd)` to change the working directory for all chunks. Your package could include a wrapper to `render` that takes care of saving the working directory to `wd`.

Comment: Thanks @CL. Nice alternative that doesn't require `rstudioapi` or the R Studio environment.

Comment: I don't think there is anything right or wrong, but it is just my choice: I choose the Rmd file (or any knitr source documents) to be the "center of the universe", meaning that any paths are relative to the path of Rmd. Some may argue the working directory of the current R session is the "center of the universe". I see the point, but my personal choice is when I'm in the Rmd document, all my reasoning about paths will start from there. This is really a hard choice to make. Both choices have pros and cons. Then I provided `opts_knit$set(root.dir)` anyway, hoping that users won't really need it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that @Yihui. Also, thanks for knitr. It's a fantastic piece of work that I use daily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to close this off:

I have selected to keep the .Rmd included in the package. The .Rmd need to move and be versioned with the package as that holds the functions they use to run.

In order to meet my requirements I style the documents to grab the working directory via the rstudio api in the form.

```
write.csv(mtcars, file = paste0(rstudioapi::getActiveProject(), "mtcars.csv"))
```

Having tested @CL's answer, this also runs and is not dependant on Rstudio as an IDE, however I know that these documents will

1. Always be accessed via the rstudio IDE
2. Always be accessed from within a specific project
3. I fear (though have not tested) that there would be the potential for other impacts from setting the working directory for the file to be artificially booted into a different WD. Potentially this could be things like child documents I might want to include later, or other code that might need to be relevant to the file path of the package installation, not the project. In this way I think (If I interpreted Yuhui correctly) the r doc is still the centre of it's own universe. It just writes it's data into another one :)